# How to respond to duplicate e-mail address during registration

Tags: security, user-input

I have a registration form in my website. I don't want to give away information about the existence of an e-mail address for security reasons. How should we, security wise, handle the "e-mail already exist" scenario without giving this information away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, its impossible, think about the email as the user name, you will inform the user that the user name is already reserved or taken, the same applies for the email address.

You can let the user enter his email twice by typing to ensure that he didn't enter other email by mistake, how ever, if the user entered his email wrongly twice, then, its his problem!

On the other hand, you won't send the confirmation email for already confirmed users, also for emails that are not stored at your side, you need to put this message in your confirmation emails:

*If you are not {First Name + Last Name} then please ignore this email* or something similar.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it so the user can create an account / sign in with openid/google/facebook/yahoo.  That way those sites hand the auth and if they can log in successfully through those you can collect any additional information you need.

You could alternatively have them create an account by first only providing an email.  You would email the user with a link where they could continue the registration process if they don't already have an account.  If an account is already created you can send an email saying something like: a request was made to create an account using this email address, but an account already exists.  If this wasn't you then....